# Sarsa with neural network to solve the Mountain Car Task

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sarsa

I am trying to implement the Episodic Semi-gradient Sarsa for Estimating q described in Sutton's book to solve the `Mountain Car Task`. To approximate `q` I want to use a `neural network`. Therefore, I came up with [this](https://gist.github.com/FlashTek/0dfddf46c4d50c4e068f1ecbad1d03b5) code. But sadly my agent is not really learning to solve the task. In some episodes the solution is found very fast (100-200 steps), but sometimes the agent needs more than 30k steps. I think, that I made some elementary mistake in my implementation, but I am not able to find it myself. Can someone help me, and point out the error/mistake in my implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the structure of the network: Instead of using the `(state, action)` pair to predict the `Q-value` of it, I changed it in the way `DQN` does it: I predict the `value` of all three possible actions for a given state and then choose the action according to this predictions. I was not able to find the problem with my previous approach, but at least this is now working.